# How to get the most out of my internship?

Tags: software-industry, internship, networking

So my internship as a software developer at a financial firm in San Francisco is coming up soon. I just wanted to get a few pointers on how to get the most out of it.

1. First, how do I go about asking for feedback properly without appearing too eager/toady. At my last internship—although a great and fun experience—I was not offered much feedback on how I was doing, whether I was going too fast/slow, whether my work was on par with my peers etc…
2. Recently I’ve become more interested in finance and I'm interested in a financial analyst type of role. To find out more about jobs in finance, I want to spend some time talking with people from the “financial analysis” departments. What is the best way to go about doing this? I imagine it'll be somewhat difficult since I’ll have to try and contact people outside my own department (Software Engineering). Also, will this be viewed by my manager as me not being interested in software engineering roles?
3. How do I network in general with my other colleagues? Should I be the guy who organizes lunch together or should I have one-on-one lunches with the people I want to network with? Any general tips/pointers?

Comment: For what it's worth, I never got any real decent feedback during my internships either. In fact, they seemed rather amazed that I was able to code at all (a seemingly rare trait in developers it seems?) , as such I was told to keep doing what I was doing as what I was doing was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general, broad advice for being an Intern: It’s all about making connections & doing good work. Nothing more, nothing less. Your specifics seem to be overthinking the scenario, but assuming good faith here is my advice on each point.

1. There should be regular meetings with whoever you are working with, correct? That’s really the only place you should ask for—or expect—feedback. And if you are not getting feedback, there must be an intern coordinator or an H.R. person you can talk about the issue with. So talk to them & be cool about it.
2. Nothing wrong with being interested in different aspects of a company. I would be 100% honest with your supervisor & just say, “I like being a developer, but I am curious about finance. Is there anyone I can reach out to?” I doubt that would be looked upon as a bad thing.
3. “Should I be the guy who organizes lunch together…” If you want to force yourself on people, go for it! But it might be best to let the social network grow naturally & just see how the culture operates. There will most likely be time to mingle, but as an intern if you attempt to force a pseudo-meeting over an awkward lunch you will not make a positive impression.